# Troubleshooting Powershell script newlines in export csv to xlsx

Tags: excel, powershell, csv

I am facing some problems with this apparently simple operation. I need to automate the procedure to export CSV files to XLSX Excel with a Powershell Script.
I found and adapted a script but I get the error "Value does not fall within the expected range" when executing the QueryTables.add(...) instruction.

I think the problem is that I have text with newlines in some cells in the csv file, those newlines are messing up my cells in the generated Excel.

```
try {
    $workingdir = "C:\Users\USER\Documents\file.csv"
    
    $workingdir = Get-Content $workingdir -Raw
    $no_linefeeds = $workingdir -replace "`n"," "
    $proper_newlines = $no_linefeeds -replace " `r","`r`n"

    $csv = $proper_newlines #dir -path $workingdir

    foreach($inputCSV in $csv){
        $outputXLSX = $inputCSV.DirectoryName + "\" + $inputCSV.Basename + ".xlsx"
        $excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application 
        $excel.DisplayAlerts = $False
        $workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Add(1)
        $worksheet = $workbook.worksheets.Item(1)

        $TxtConnector = ("TEXT;" + $inputCSV)
        $Connector = $worksheet.QueryTables.add($TxtConnector,$worksheet.Range("A1"))
        $query = $worksheet.QueryTables.item($Connector.name)

        $query.TextFileOtherDelimiter = $Excel.Application.International(3)

        $query.TextFileParseType  = 1
        $query.TextFileColumnDataTypes = ,2 * $worksheet.Cells.Columns.Count
        $query.AdjustColumnWidth = 1

        $query.Refresh()
        $query.Delete()

        $Workbook.SaveAs($outputXLSX,51)
        $excel.Quit()
    }   
}
catch {
    Write-Warning $Error[0]
}

Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"
```

Can you help me spot the problem?
Thank you

Comment: You do know that Excel reads CSV-files natively as imports?

Comment: Hi Dennis, thank you for your answer. 
Yes, I do know that Excel does that. I am facing no problems doing this procedure through the graphical Excell application: Data -> Import Data -> CSV.
I am trying to automate this procedure to work with huge amount of CSVs which also have dirty data in them (eg. newlines, chars in number fields, etc...).
Correct me if I misunderstood what you meant, thank you.

Comment: Are you able to import the CSV-files into PowerShell using `Import-Csv` first? That should help clean up the files if Excel have some issues with them. That will of course add time to processing the files.

Comment: Don't repeatedly create a new Excel com object inside the loop. Do that just once above the loop and quit and destroy it after the loop.